# Twain scanner customizing for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twain

I am using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1376/NET-TWAIN-image-scanner and I am trying to adapt it to MVC. The problem is in this line of code

tw.Init(this.Handle);

this.Handle is a IntPtr, and I dont know how to change that to use in MVC.

tw.Init methods code:

```
public void Init( IntPtr hwndp )
{
      Finish();

TwRC rc = DSMparent( appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Parent, TwMSG.OpenDSM, ref hwndp );           

if( rc == TwRC.Success )

        {

rc = DSMident( appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Identity, TwMSG.GetDefault, srcds );

        if( rc == TwRC.Success )

            hwnd = hwndp;

        else

rc = DSMparent( appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Parent, TwMSG.CloseDSM, ref hwndp );

        }

    }
```

Comment: How are you planning to use a scanner through a web-site? initiate a scan on server site by a request for a web-page?

Comment: no. Scan should start on the client machine. I did it with WIA drivers but now I must do the same with TWAIN.

Comment: do you reaslise there is no way to control hardware on client machine? The client machine uses browser and there is no way for browser to initiate scanning by executing some server-side code.

Comment: I did it with WIA, I am just trying to do the same with TWAIN.

Comment: WIA on client machine? Initiated scan on some other computer via a browser? I find it hard to believe

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/4ocqsbvo1/

Comment: That is exactly what I'm talking about - you are initiating a scan on a server machine, not client. And because your localhost is client and a server at the same time, this works for you. But if I connect to your web-site from my machine, the scanning procedure will start on your PC, not on mine.

Comment: Now that I start to think it does make sense. I will test it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TWAIN plugin to control a scanner in your website. This article might help:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618514/Scan-and-Upload-Documents-in-ASP-NET-MVC-App-using